# Extending an Ace code editor language scheme

Tags: editor, ace-editor

Is it possible with the ace code editor to develop a custom language scheme that would **extend** an existing one?

I want to provide a code editor which would be basically HTML, but with some domain-specific meta language, such as:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {#for obj in arr#}
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
    {#endfor#}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and obviously want the meta language to be syntax colored and foldable as well. What is the right approach for it? Or maybe there's a better code editor out there for my purpose than Ace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see handlebars mode in ace which does the same thing https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/handlebars.js#L6

Comment: Sounds like a solution.